# On Ask Different, freebsd is a synonym of unix

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Preamble

Why do you pull BSD and Linux people into your [business](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Context

The moderators of this site don't understand what [synonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym) means (*"exactly or nearly the same as another word"*) and put *`freebsd, bsd, linux, ubuntu`* into the [synonyms](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/unix/synonyms) of [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix). The related issues are listed below

Done

- The question [tag synonym cleanup - sed and awk / unix](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/synonym-cleanup-sed-and-awk#4212) asks to remove *`sed`* and *`awk`* from the [synonyms](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/unix/synonyms) of the tag [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) on *AskDifferent*.

Work in progress

- This question asks to remove *`freebsd`* from the [synonyms](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/unix/synonyms) of the tag [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) on *AskDifferent*.
- The question [Separate Linux tag from Unix](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2763/separate-linux-tag-from-unix/3647) asks to remove *`linux`* from the [synonyms](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/unix/synonyms) of the tag [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) on *AskDifferent*.
- The feature-request [Add option 'exclude these sites' in a filter rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388727/add-option-exclude-these-sites-in-a-filter-rule), if implemented, would allow blacklisting sites in [tag-search](https://stackexchange.com/filters)
- The feature request [Add the ability to exclude sites in global searches](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316399/add-the-ability-to-exclude-sites-in-global-searches#comment1296258_388751), if implemented, would allow blacklisting sites in [global-search](https://stackexchange.com/search).

---

- Simple solution would be renaming the *unix* tag to *unixly* (see the answer below).
- This question might be considered either a `bug` or `feature-request`. It was changed to `discussion` by the moderator.

---

**Remove *`freebsd`* as a [synonym](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/unix/synonyms) of the tag [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix)  on *Ask Different*, please.**

1. In the first place, what is the solid argument for *`freebsd`* being a synonym to *`unix`* on *`AskDifferent`*?
2. When I [filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters) by the tag *`freebsd`* I'm not interested in questions tagged [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) on *`AskDifferent`*
3. Mac people use to tag their questions [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) instead of [macos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos). For example, [how to let `clear` command just clears the current screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459137/how-to-let-clear-command-just-clears-the-current-screen)
4. I'd like to avoid answering [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) questions to find out it's about [macos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos). For example, to avoid the comments in [Pipe to mv command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365838/pipe-to-mv-command)
5. It is not clear whether the questions about using the 3rd party software (FreeBSD, BSD, Linux, Ubuntu) are on-topic here. If they are off-topic (see the answer below) the [synonyms](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/unix/synonyms) *`freebsd, bsd,linux, ubuntu`* should be removed.

---

If you want to improve something put the default first tag *`apple`* to all *`AskDifferent`* questions. The [topics](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says it's monothematic:

- Apple HW
- Apple SW
- Apple services
- 3rd party ... use with Apple products

Any browser tab label of *`AskDifferent`* should be of the form:

```
apple - <title of the question>
```

The rules are strange at the moment

- [How to let `clear` command just clears the current screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459137/how-to-let-clear-command-just-clears-the-current-screen): 1st tag *`macos`* in the label
- [Can't partition Macintosh HD or increase free space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431807/cant-partition-macintosh-hd-or-increase-free-space-error-shows-the-target-dis): No tag in the label at all
- [Unable to access new Macbook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459141/unable-to-access-new-macbook-pro-m2-using-share-disk-mode): 2nd tag *`network`* in the label. Why not the 1st tag *`macbook-pro`*? Because *`Mackbook Pro`* is in the title?

---

Answers to some questions from the below comments:

Q1: ***"Are you arguing that each name is important enough to have a unique tag here?"***

A: Yes. The [synonyms](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/unix/synonyms) *`freebsd, bsd, linux, ubuntu`* of your tag [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) not only pollute the network-wide feeds but also disable proper searching by these synonyms at *AskDifferent*.

---

Q2: ***"Are you saying that all flavors of Unix should have distinct tags, none of which should be synonyms of Unix?"***

A: No. Not all flavors. [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) is a superset of many operating systems. Include them as needed. AskDiferent tag [*synonyms for unix*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/unix/synonyms) are: `freebsd, bsd, linux, ubuntu`. If I search tag *`freebsd`* on
[AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags) I get the 'Mac branded' description of [*unix*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix?tab=Newest)! This is absurd. You should remove all the synonyms here and add them as tags if needed.

---

Q3: ***"'They can add both' is a counterargument to deduplicate them."***

A: This depends on the description of your tag [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix). The current description is not sustainable in the long term. The mess resulting from the set of [unix synonyms](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/unix/synonyms), which are not synonyms even by far, is growing. Take a look at the [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) site. Among the [topics](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are both:

- Using or administering a *nix desktop or server
- The Unix foundation underlying MacOS

Take a look at the proper set of tags. For example, [[macos] [freebsd]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos+freebsd) questions. This is how your tags should look like.

---

Q4: ***"That implies some effort to retag questions."***

A: Yes. Remove the [synonyms](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/unix/synonyms) and create tags instead. Then, add these tags to the [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) questions. There are 1060 of them atm. Nearly half of them can be easily recognized by the title: [gnu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunix%5D+title%3Agnu) (10), [freebsd](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunix%5D+title%3Afreebsd) (2), [bsd](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunix%5D+title%3Absd) (7), [linux](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunix%5D+title%3Alinux) (226), [ubuntu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunix%5D+title%3Aubuntu) (166), [sed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunix%5D+title%3Ased) (12), [awk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunix%5D+title%3Aawk) (3), [posix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunix%5D+title%3Aposix) (2).

Let the users create new tags as needed.

---

5: Quoting from the [comment](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4208/on-ask-different-freebsd-is-a-synonym-of-unix#comment9419_4208) by the administrator @Monomeeth: "Ask Different is for users of Apple products, be it hardware, software or service - all Apple. And, when it's about a **3rd party hardware, software or service, they're only on topic here if the question is about using them with an Apple product**"

A: The answer by another administrator @nohillside contradicts your statement (in bold).

Q: "Not sure I understand the point about the apple tag."

A: Because of the [topics](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) all *AskDifferent* questions should be tagged *`apple`*. SE concatenates a label in the browser tab from the first tag and the question title. As a result, all *AskDifferent* questions should have a label of the form `apple - <title of the question>`. Not in the form `unix - <title of the question>` if the first tag in the question is *`unix`*.

Comment: Not sure I understand the point about the `apple` tag: All questions here relate to Apple products, what is the value of a tag which applies to all questions?

Comment: Also, within the context of the site, can you list questions which would benefit from having a distinct `freebsd` tag? And if yes, would the majority of askers share that distinction?

Comment: Anyway, if you look at the [description](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) of the `unix` tag, it seems to be an appropriate tag for the „clear“ question.

Comment: I wouldn't support adding `Apple` as a default first tag. After all, Ask Different is for users of Apple products, be it hardware, software or service - all Apple. And, when it's about a 3rd party hardware, software or service, they're only on topic here if the question is about using them with an Apple product, so it's implied that every question relates to Apple anyway.

Comment: However, if a solid argument can be put forth on removing `freebsd` as a synonym for Unix, I'm open to supporting that. But  I agree with @nohillside - can you list questions which would benefit from having a distinct `freebsd` tag? And if we went down that path, are you saying that all flavors of `Unix` should have distinct tags, none of which should be synonyms of `Unix`?

Comment: **All** AskDifferent posts are about Apple products, an `apple` tag is simply redundant. Tags should be used to make topics easy to follow, not to look nice in a UI.

Comment: [tag:apple] tag would be (or has already been) blocked as [an intrinsic tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181772/241919) though.

Comment: Microsoft is a vendor of software running on Apple devices, so a tag may be useful. We also have an adobe tag (and probably some more in the same category).

Comment: To repeat a point made earlier: which unix-labeled questions would *benefit* from a distinct freebsd tag? And do you have examples for AD questions which would *not* be labeled apple if we would have such a tag?

Comment: I'm not much changed in [my thinking from 2019 on the unix tag](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3647/5472).

Comment: I rolled back your edit about what I apparently said. Everybody interested can read it directly in the answer below, also, if you quote me, please do so correctly and don't change the meaning while still attributing it to me.

Comment: You keep misquoting us and pulling statements out of context. Please read the first part of my answer more carefully.

Comment: The point is your answer contradicts not only your own [comment](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2763/separate-linux-tag-from-unix/3647#comment8712_3647) but the [comment](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4208/on-ask-different-freebsd-is-a-synonym-of-unix#comment9419_4208) of the moderator @
Monomeeth as well.

Comment: Also, not sure we get your point. Is there a specific practical problem in using AD you are trying to solve here? The whole discussion is rather theoretical at the moment.

Comment: The „contradiction“ within the Q&A here comes from a misinterpretation of the remarks Monomeeth and I made, not sure how I can help you with that.

Comment: @nohillside Based on the user's Meta Stack Exchange posts, their main complaint is that they are subscribed to a network-wide feed of [freebsd]-tagged questions, and they're finding that the synonym here on this site is polluting their feed with questions that aren't related to FreeBSD. They want that feed to only consist of questions that are directly related to FreeBSD, so they want the synonym removed for that purpose.

Comment: @gparyani I read this out of their Meta.SE post as well. Just hope that they don’t expect a whole site to change their tags for something they can easily manage themselves (e.g. by just ignoring any matches their query gets on AD).

Comment: I don’t know what more your edit brought to the table and why this is such a critical issue.  And this is coming from someone responding here in Firefox running in the LXQT Desktop Environment running on a mid-2007 (white) MacBook running FreeBSD-13.2-RELEASE.  [Can we stop beating this horse](https://i.imgur.com/GCnGDty.jpg)?

Comment: This is not the right site if you have problems with FreeBSD on your Mac.

Comment: No @VladimirBotka - it’s not.  A better site is [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). At most, here you might get some assistance with installing FreeBSD on a Mac because you have to deal with the idiosyncrasies that only Apple seems to be able to implement.  After that, everything is essentially a FreeBSD/Unix question.

Comment: I agree.  Unix & Linux is a better site. What part of my previous comment you don't agree with? You should read carefully what your moderator is saying: *`FreeBSD (and its variants) itself are off-topic on Apple.SE`* because third-party software is on-topic only when **associated** for use with Apple products.

Comment: Nobody said anything about off topic.  The issue is *demand* for FreeBSD here on AD.  You can ask all the FreeBSD questions on Apple hardware you want; whether you get an answer because there’s people with that knowledge is a totally different story.

Answer (score 5):

**I don't see the need for a specific [freebsd](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freebsd) tag as questions about using FreeBSD (and its variants) itself are as off-topic on Apple.SE as are questions about using Linux, Windows or VAX/VMS.**

To quote from https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (emphasis added)

> **Ask Different is for users of Apple products**. If you have a question about a practical problem you are trying to solve as a user of...
>
> - Apple hardware
> - Apple software
> - Apple services including iTunes Connect (selling music, books, apps)
> - third-party hardware, services and software when associated for use with Apple products.
>
> ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!

*Any* question here already has an implicit [apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple) tag because *all* questions are asked within an Apple context.

This also limits the scope of all the other tags on Apple.SE, for instance the [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) tag you mentioned above. Basically this tag means "question related to the Unix/BSD foundation, command line shells, or any binaries & scripts running in such a shell, *within the constraints of macOS/iOS*" (which basically is also reflected in the [tag definition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix)). Any answer to such a question is to be given within the Apple world.

Keep in mind that for most end users of Apple products (which is the audience of this site), "Unix" usually means "What runs in Terminal". So having [freebsd](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freebsd), [linux](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) and some other commonly used terms as synonyms of [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) helps to keep the more "unixly" questions together, without getting lost in details. If people are looking for generic Unix answers (or even answers considering all the flavors of Unix/BSD/Linux/Hurd/...), then asking/searching on Unix&Linux is for sure the better way to go.

Comment: Your statement: *`"I don't see the need for a specific freebsd tag as questions about using FreeBSD (and its variants) itself are as off-topic on Apple.SE as are questions about using Linux ..."`* is in contradiction with your previous comment on [Separate Linux tag from Unix](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2763/separate-linux-tag-from-unix/3647#comment8712_3647): *`"... unix is used both for questions relating to the Unix-like parts of macOS and for installing Unix-like OSes on Apple hardware. Both are on-topic on AD. ... I would be strongly in favor of a split here "`*

Comment: @VladimirBotka I learned in the meantime that this would not have been practical because it doesn't help how well-structured and well-intended tags are: If users afterwards don't use them as intended, having too many detailed tags is more harmful than useful. But thanks for pointing out that I thought about this differently in the past.

Comment: It's also obvious from the context that the idea of having separate tags never got traction with the AD community and wasn't pursued further.

Comment: As a person who chooses FreeBSD over Linux by a large margin, I would love to have a tag for it (i.e. FreeBSD on MacBook) , but given the lack of engagement, it doesn’t make sense.  Maybe I’m wrong here, but anything FreeBSD related, I head over to Unix & Linux on SE

Comment: @Allan, Searching the tag *`freebsd`* returns all questions about *`unix, gnu, bsd, linux, ubuntu, sed, awk, posix`*. From this perspective, one might consider the engagement rather large.

Comment: How many of those are bona fide FreeBSD questions, @VladimirBotka?

Comment: I'd like to know too. See my first question in bold.

Comment: It was (mostly) rhetorical, there’s really not a lot here @VladimirBotka

Comment: @Allan, and it seems that it shouldn't be here anything at all. Among the [Unix topics](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) you can find: *`The Unix foundation underlying MacOS`*.

Comment: @VladimirBotka if you look at the whole paragraph at https://wiki.freebsd.org/Myths#FreeBSD_is_Just_macOS_Without_the_Good_Bits, you can see that the relationship between FreeBSD and macOS is way more complex than just „FreeBSD is the foundation of macOS“. It‘s not that relevant though: if people have FreeBSD questions, they get good answers when asking at a site where FreeBSD people hang out. If people have Windows questions -> Windows-focused site. In both cases, AD isn’t a good place even though both OS run on Apple hardware.

Comment: @nohilside, the point is *`if people have MacOS questions about Unix, they get good answers when asking at a site where Unix people hang out`*. The [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) site provides atm 800 [macos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) Q/A. All tags and their combinations `[macos][gnu]` (16), `[macos][bsd]` (47), `[macos][lnux]` (254), `[macos][ubuntu]` (94), `[macos][sed]` (97), `[macos][awk]` (47), `[macos][posix]` (12), `[macos] [freebsd]` (29) work as expected on [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: That argument to nohillside’s point doesn’t strengthen your position @VladimirBotka.  We have 271 questions here that contain  “FreeBSD”.  The most recent ones are mine and most of the rest don’t ask BSD related questions but rather make reference to it.

Comment: @Allan, this discussion is about tags and synonyms. Don't you see that the [synonyms](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/unix/synonyms) *`gnu, freebsd, bsd, linux, ubuntu, sed, awk, posix`* of your tag [tag:unix] not only pollute the network-wide feeds but also disable proper searching by these synonyms at *AskDifferent*? The 271 [FreeBSD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=FreeBSD) questions at *AskDifferent* are not related to these problems. My previous comment was to show you what a properly managed set of MacOS 'unix' tags looks like.

Comment: @VladimirBotka Both Superuser and Unix&Linux have a broad scope covering „all“ computers and „everything related to any kind of Unix and its tools“ respectively. AD covers (on the Mac side) macOS and questions related to it, so it‘s kind of natural that some tags are defined differently.

Comment: Also, if I would have to make a guess, most people in AD don‘t use tags for searching, and those who do use it to subscribe to updates on some topics specific to AD.

Comment: @nohillside Yes but you can't do that with the unix tag and its synonyms as it is too broad

Comment: @mmmmmm Which brings us back to a question I asked when then question came first up: Which questions on AD would benefit from a freebsd tag while still being ontopic?

Comment: My answer to **Q4** provides you with a hint. There are ~1000 [tag:unix] questions. ~400 can be easily tagged by the title. The other ~600 are potential candidates. This can be further reduced to 35 by searching [\[unix\] body: "freebsd"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunix%5D+body%3A+%22freebsd%22).

Comment: @nohillside for AD I don't think the FreeBSD tag is useful. The split of linux, sed awk and removal of unix would be useful

Comment: @VladimirBotka If you look at the 35 (or even at the 600) you'll see that most of them are not actually about FreeBSD itself, so a FreeBSD tag wouldn't even apply.

Comment: @mmmmmm I would support a proposal to burry sed and awk for good.

Comment: @nohillside Added https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/synonym-cleanup-sed-and-awk